# Conditional ORDER BY depending on column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-order-by

I need to write a query that does this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 
FROM a list of tables (Joins, etc)
ORDER BY Column X, Column Y, Column Z
```

If `ColumnX` is `NOT NULL`, then at the moment, I reselect, using a slightly different `ORDER BY`.

So, I do the same query, twice. If the first one has a `NULL` in a certain column, I return that row from my procedure. However, if the value isn't `NULL` - I have to do another identical select, except, order by a different column or two.

What I do now is select it into a temp table the first time. Then check the value of the column. If it's OK, return the temp table, else, redo the select and return that result set.

More details:

In english, the question I am asking the database:

Return my all the results for certain court appearance (By indexed foreign key). I expect around 1000 rows. Order it by the date of the appearance (column, not indexed, nullable), last appearance first. Check an 'importId'. If the import ID is not NULL for that top 1 row, then we need to run the same query - but this time, order by the Import ID (Last one first), and return that row. Or else, just return the top 1 row from the original query.

Comment: What version of SQL Server, and can you speak in more specific terms? e.g. what are the data types of the different columns you're trying to order by?

Comment: Your approach seems reasonable. Would need to know a lot more details about tables, indexes, and the query to see if there was any way that you could avoid doing the 2 queries as efficiently.

Comment: The problem is - can this be done in one query, or would it be OK to duplicate the query? The query relies on good indexing etc.. and is fast enough. But I was wondering if there was a better way to do this instead of SELECT into Temp .... check field ... redo select.

Comment: There probably is, but we need more details.

Comment: Sorry - we're using SQL Server 2008

Comment: I'll upload the query when I get to the office.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd say the BEST way to do this is in a **single query** is a `CASE` statement...

```
SELECT TOP 1 FROM ... ORDER BY 
    (CASE WHEN column1 IS NULL THEN column2 ELSE column1 END)
```

Comment: This (and coalesce) could make the query plan much much worse than 2 separate `TOP 1` queries that both use indexes.

Comment: @Martin Smith: I assume he wanted a way to do it in one call based on the first line of his post "...to write **a** query..."

Comment: The comments clarify they are "wondering if there was a better way to do this "

Comment: I don't know if we can use a CASE on the ORDER BY... because the CASE only works one one "ROW" cell (CASE WHEN COLUMN1 IS NULL....). I have modified my question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) function to turn nullable columns into orderby friendly values.

```
 SELECT   CAST(COALESCE(MyColumn, 0) AS money) AS Column1 
 FROM     MyTable
 ORDER BY Column1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used in Firebird (columns are numeric):

```
ORDER BY CASE <condition> WHEN <value> THEN <column1>*1000 + <column2> ELSE <column3>*1000 + <column4> END
```