# Conditionally change sort direction in SQL

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have an interesting take on [a similar question that was asked many years ago on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464434/conditional-order-by-depending-on-column-values)

For simplicity, suppose I have a table with three columns:

```
+----+------+-------+
| id | cond | value |
+----+------+-------+
| 1  |  1   |  "A"  |
| 2  |  0   |  "B"  |
| 3  |  1   |  "C"  |
| 4  |  0   |  "D"  |
| 5  |  1   |  "E"  |
+----+------+-------+
```

Now I want to sort this table first by `cond`, then by `value` ***ascending*** if `cond` is 0 and ***descending*** if `cond` is 1. The final sorted table should look like:

```
+----+------+-------+
| id | cond | value |
+----+------+-------+
| 2  |  0   |  "B"  |
| 4  |  0   |  "D"  |
| 5  |  1   |  "E"  |
| 3  |  1   |  "C"  |
| 1  |  1   |  "A"  |
+----+------+-------+
```

Note that I can't depend on `value` to be numerical, so I can't do something clever like:

```
order by cond, (case when cond = 0 then value else -value end)
```

Comment: Have you tried `case when cond = 0 then ascii(value) else -ascii(value) end`

Comment: @juergend The `ascii(value)` solution works for single letters, but not for multi-letter strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two separated conditional `cond` to order your result:

```
select *
from yourtable
order by 
    cond, 
    case when cond = 0 then `value` else 1 end,
    case when cond = 1 then `value` else 1 end desc
```

See **[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be88b7/1)** here.

Answer (score 1):

Add row number after sorting by value. Then do your conditional ordering:

```
select *
from (
  select a.*, @r := @r + 1 AS rn
  from (
    select *
    from mytable
    order by value) a
  join (select @r := 0) b) a
order by cond, (case when cond then -rn else rn end)
```

Another way to convert ordering to int:

```
select a.*, count(b.id) c
from mytable a
join mytable b on a.cond = b.cond and a.value > b.value
group by a.id
order by a.cond, case when a.cond then -c else c end
```