# How can i turn order by dynamic?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tried to order this sql with a conditional if

```
  FROM sgm_whatsapp
  WHERE `phone_number` = '51996268989' 
  IF(delivery_date > answer_date, ORDER BY delivery_date DESC, ORDER BY answer_date DESC);
```

It isn't working. Can someone help me?

Comment: you can use sql `case` check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7464492/3864485)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you add an if statement in ORDER BY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550942/can-you-add-an-if-statement-in-order-by)

Comment: Take consideration that in this situation, as explained in the referer answer, CASE is better choice than IF function

Comment: For future reference, "it isn't working" isn't a helpful problem description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order by IF

```
    FROM sgm_whatsapp
      WHERE `phone_number` = '51996268989' 
      order by       
   IF(delivery_date > answer_date, delivery_date , answer_date) desc;
```

Comment: Worked. thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT fields
FROM sgm_whatsapp
  WHERE `phone_number` = '51996268989' 
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN delivery_date > answer_date THEN delivery_date
ELSE answer_date 
END DESC
```